# Is there a cross-platform way to convert SVG file to PNG at runtime?

Tags: java, cross-platform, svg

I need to convert SVG files to PNG files at first launch of a game and then save these PNG files to some assets folder. I'm wondering if i can achieve it on both Desktop and Android. The reason why i want to use SVG is to have resolution-independent assets at first and then convert them into PNG file with needed size according to user's screen resolution so there is no need to store  multiple files per one asset. Is it possible to use one library or should i use different solutions for Desktop and Android? I'm using libGDX framework.

Any other ways to achieve resolution independency will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

The only solution i found is using two libraries: one for Desktop (i think Batik is the best choice https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) and one for Android (i was told that AndroidSVG is the best of Android SVG libraries but it still has some limitations https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/).

Comment: Have you looked into [this](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/)?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt searching has shown that there is no easy way to make Batik work on Android.

Comment: @nikoliazekter Android isn't mentioned anywhere in the question—please edit. If you've tried something which didn't work, list that too.

Comment: @Anko "I'm wondering if i can achieve it on both Desktop and **Android**.", "Is it possible to use one library or should i use different solutions for Desktop and **Android**?", "Is there a **cross-platform** way to convert SVG file to PNG at runtime?" Isn't that enough?

Comment: @nikoliazekter Oops, sorry, I was inattentive. The Android part is quite clear.